# Event inside an event, keeps loading all over again

Tags: jquery

im building an ecommerce web site using jQuery and i ran into a little problem.
I have a "My cart" button which should list all products added on mouseenter event. Problem is i that i have a button which removes specific product. Once i click that button it gets back to calling first ajax request over and over again thus not allowing me to remove the product. I know there is a problem somewhere with the events but i cant figure it out. 
Here is the code:

```
// My cart
$('div#cartButton').mouseenter(function() {
    //var remProduct, notLogedIn, pCartError;
    var language = $.cookie('lang');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./locales/lang_js_"+language+".xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache:false,
        success: function(xml) {
            var remProduct = $(xml).find('remProduct').text();
            var notLogedIn = $(xml).find('notLogedIn').text();
            var cartEmpty = $(xml).find('cartEmpty').text();
            var pCartError = $(xml).find('error').text();

            // Ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "./ajax/loadcart.php",
                cache:false,
                beforeSend: function() {$('div#cartDPStatus').empty().html('<img src="./images/al_2.gif" />')},
                success: function(response) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                    switch(data['status']) {
                        case 'OK':
                            $('div#cartDPStatus').empty();
                            $('div#cartViewDropDown').html(data['products']);
                            // Remove from cart
                            $('span.cqpRemove').click(function() {
                                $(this).parent('div.cartQProduct').hide(200, function() {
                                    $(this).parent('div.cartQProduct').remove();
                                    if($('div.cartQProduct').length <= 0) $('div.cartViewDropDown').empty().html('<div id="cartDPStatus">'+cartEmpty+'</div>');

                                    console.log($('div.cartQProduct').length);
                                });
                            });
                        break;
                        case 'EMPTY':
                            $('div#cartDPStatus').empty().html(cartEmpty);
                        break;
                        case 'BAD':
                            $('div#cartDPStatus').empty().html('<img src="./images/icon_error.png" style="height:24px !important"/>&nbsp;'+pCartError);
                        break;
                        case 'NOTLOGEDIN':
                            $('div#cartDPStatus').empty().html('<img src="./images/icon_error.png" style="height:24px !important"/>&nbsp;'+notLogedIn);
                        break;
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('div#cartDPStatus').empty().html(pCartError);
                }       
            });
        }
    });
    $('div#cartViewDropDown').slideDown(300);
});
```

First ajax request is for reading language xml file, once it's complete second request loads products and then the click event should remove that element.

I hope you understand where the problem is. Once i click that button it gets back to loading all over again and again while my mouse is over that div element.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
My html looks like this

```
<div id="cartButton">
   <div id="cartViewDropDown">
       <div id="cartDPStatus">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does your html loo likek? Do you have a mouseleave? Maybe it's possible that your div#cartViewDropDown lays over the div#cartButton and the mouseleave is triggered. If you hide the div#cartViewDropDown in your leave, your enter get involked again. But it depends of your html. Is your cartViewDropDown div element inside your cartButton div element?

Comment: I added my html layout above. I have mouseleave event, div#cartViewDropDown is inside #cartButton because of the mouseenter event, otherwise the drop down would close once i leave that area

Comment: Ok thanks, that looks fine. Maybe you can recreate your problem in a fiddle. I Created [one](http://jsfiddle.net/Zps52/) for you, but this works. Also there might be a problem with your ajax. Have you tried it without the ajax calls?

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/miki86/VSq9n/) Looks like it doesnt work here either, only when clicked on TEST 3, because it immediately register new mouseenter event and it adds it again. I haven't tried without ajax because i dont believe its an ajax problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('p.remove').click(function() {
     $(this).hide(); 
});
```

The event is triggered every time you remove the DOM element. I don't know why, but if you use `hide()` it should work like you want it.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSq9n/7/).

Comment: Or i can add something like this too keep track if the drop down is open or not. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/miki86/VSq9n/)

Comment: Sure, this works also. You should then wrap all into a class to avoid that removed is accessible globally.
Please mark as answered if it helps you.